# Is there an opposite of "upmost"?

Tags: antonyms

I'm writing something that involves the upmost, the righmost, the leftmost and the... damn. It was coming along quite beautifully.

What would your choice be?

Comment: Are you describing position in a two- or three-dimensional space? What's the orientation? I like the question!

Comment: Why yes, I'm referring to the corners of a 2D plane.

Comment: Umm...downmost?

Comment: You could turn the paper 90 degrees and use right and leftmost again!

Comment: Sadly, 'upmost' is a word that usually is a typo for 'utmost'

Comment: I wouldn't be afraid to use "downmost," especially if you've already established a precedent with -most. Your readers will understand. If you're opposed to using it, though, I've used "floor" to describe the area closest a viewer of a two-dimensional plane. Note that this depends on orientation, though. Wish I had a better answer

Comment: @jboneca I guess it wouldn't be a crime to use downmost here. The goal is to make myself understood, not to delight anyone. However, it's always tempting to try and make it sound better. Maybe I should push for a new convention regarding this issue in my field... I'm sure I'm not the first one to encounter this problem.

Comment: @broncoAbierto certainly not. It sounds like you're in a technical field, and I imagine you aren't the only person to have this problem. The only context I've seen "downmost" is in religious pieces, so it's unlikely anyone would be confused by what you're trying to say. This is especially true if "downmost" occurs in the context of "rightmost" and "leftmost."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lowest thing is the *nethermost* one, which the OED defines as “Lowest, undermost, furthest down.”

Answer (score 2):

The correct pair would be *uppermost* & *lowermost*.

Avoid using *upmost* for at least two reasons: it's not very formal, it has no antonym :)

Alternately, *topmost* & *bottommost* (I would not recommend, though.)

Answer (score 1):

*Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*, Eleventh Edition (2003) gives a one-word definition for *upmost*: "UPPERMOST." The logical opposite of *uppermost* is *lowermost* or *lowest*.

As Oldcat notes in a comment beneath the original post, "upmost" may be a confusion with  *utmost*, which derives from Old English *utmest* meaning "outermost" or "farthest." The opposite of that word would be *innermost* or *nearest*, though in the sense of "the maximum possible," *utmost* would have as its opposite *least*.

Comment: All so fine, but where's the *answer*?

Answer (score 0):

'nadir' is the very bottom...opposite of 'zenith'

Comment: This is beautiful, although the context demands a more pragmatic immediacy.

Answer (score 0):

'top' and 'bottom'
'highest' and 'lowest'